# Uppercase variables no longer being displayed in different color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the Dracula theme for VSC and uppercase variables had always been displayed in purple instead of white. For some reason, this suddenly changed, and now they are no longer differentiated. How can I override the settings so that uppercase variables are again formatted in a different color?

Comment: Could you please add a small snippet of code and indicate what you would like highlighted in a different color? I am looking at vscode's color customization settings and I don't see an option for differentiating between lower and uppercase variables.

Comment: Upper case variables such as: obj.UPPERCASE_VARIABLE = "test1"; const UPPERCASE_VARIABLE = "test2"; would be a different color, but not single uppercase letters such as const num = R.inc(1);